# How to add cookie which specific domain using selenium.creatCookie

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I cannot use function `selenium.createCookie` to `setcookie` which have domain agrument specific. (Using Jmeter still OK )

I used as following:

```
selenium.createCookie("name=value", "domain=localhost");
selenium.open("localhost/sample/login");
```

Do you have any ideas for this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie.Builder("name", "value").domain("domain").build();
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

Just make sure you import the right kind of cookie first:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Cookie;
```

Also, you might not be able to add cookies for a domain which you aren't currently on. So first navigate to the desired domain, and then addCookie.